# Как отладить C# core консольное приложение?

Tags: c#, .net-core

Тесты показали запаздывание программы, решил воспользоваться профайлингом. Сперва пробовал встроенный в 2017 студию. В решении два проекта, в одном находится проверяемый класс, в другом тесты. По первому проекту ошибка: "PRF0002: Ошибка инструментирования с указанными параметрами: /u "D:\work\Commutator\NetworkCommutator\obj\Release\netcoreapp2.0\NetworkCommutator.dll"   /excludesmallfuncs". 
Тогда мне посоветовали ANTS profiler, но он позволяет работать только с исполняемыми файлами, а проекты консольные приложения в виде DLL под dotnet.exe. В сети информации не нашёл. Как же мне обнаружить тонкое место?

Comment: а что значит "запаздывание программы"?

Comment: Есть класс, который задерживает входные сигналы. Их два варианта. Прогнал сто секундный тест с частотой входного сигнала тридцать герц, запаздыванием две секунды Время выхода последнего сигнала и конца теста должно быть сто две секунды, а оба варианта опоздали на полторы секунды. Один вариант позволяет проверить, когда сигналы из очереди запаздывают, скажем, на период. Оказалось десять процентов таких "опоздавших".

Comment: значит и искать вам нужно в классах задерживающих сигналы, смотреть их константы и смотреть как они работают, на что они время забирают, если есть таймер до выхода ответа, значит надо смотреть, его, возможно изменять.

Comment: А я что хочу? Нужен профайлер.

Comment: дебажить пробовали?

Comment: Конечно. И параметры вызова регулируемого класса менял. Это приводит не только к уменьшению запаздывания, но даже к преждевременному концу теста, что совсем непонятно. А надо отладить оба класса. Первый на потоках, второй на таймере с очередью. Неужели нет профайлера для таких случаев?

Comment: Пока нет профайлера, занимался тестами, и вот что выяснилось. Похоже для таймера есть оптимальное время периода. Попробую сменить подход к таймеру. А профайлер всё равно нужен!